# mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet

Tags: mysql

I installed Mysql5.7 long time ago, afterwards I uninstalled it and installed MariaDB disabling apparmor (mysql) profile.

Now I uninstalled MariaDB and I'm trying to install mysql5.7 and I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I get this error when I use `sudo dpkg --configre -a` too.

I install the package using `sudo apt install mysql-server`.
I tried to follow some guide online, I removed `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst` purged mariadb, mysql and tried a lot of things.

Comment: Can you post the exit in English?

Comment: Done, I printed the error in English.

Comment: This seems to be an error with the installation script, if I'm not totally wrong. `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory` You might want to try googling that error, there seems to be multiple answers on how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I solved in this way:

- I used `Software & Updates` application to remove mariadb sources
- executed the followings steps (ref https://askubuntu.com/a/934576):
- `sudo apt purge mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-server`
- `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt -f install`
- `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Comment: does not work. Additional message is:

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
      Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) .

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it for me (MySQL 8.0 - Ubuntu 20.04)

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql\* libmysql\*
sudo apt autoremove
```

But the package "mysql-client-core-8.0" don't uninstall, so...

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-client-core-8.0
sudo apt-get purge mysql\* libmysql\*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

No more errors!

Comment: I had forgotten to stop my docker db, after stopping that it worked

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg -P mysql-server mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

The step `dpkg -l | grep -i mysql` will show you all mysql modules, which are installed. It should be empty before the next steps.

Answer (score 1):

This error could also happen if the port (3306) is being used by another app. In my case, I had a docker container running mysql which was using the 3306 port. Hence my local mysql installation failed to configure.

```
$ sudo netstat -nltp | grep LISTEN | grep 3306
$ sudo netstat -nltp | grep LISTEN | grep 3306
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1017033/docker-prox 

sudo apt purge --auto-remove mysql*
sudo rm -r /etc/mysql
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql*

sudo apt install mysql-client-8.0 mysql-server-8.0 --fix-broken -y
```